# How to update a database stored in assets folder Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, assets

How do you re-copy a database that is stored in the assets folder for an android studio project?

I am using the Android SQLite Assets helper class

```
package com.acorney.migration;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

/**
* Created by acorney on 25/07/2016.
*/
public class databaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String TAG = SQLiteAssetHelper.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "peopleDatabase.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public databaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

And I create an instance of it in my MainActivity

```
databaseHelper dataB;
dataB = new databaseHelper(this);
```

This, I think, creates an empty database in data/data and copies the database from Assets into it

However, I have updated the database from outside the app (using SQLite browser) and saved it back to the assets folder.
How could I copy the database's updates into the application?

Eventually, the app needs to read and write to this database - so that changes are saved to the database in the assets folder

And, when the app starts up, the app should just create a new instance of the database in the assets folder.

**Basically - I want all database changes to happen in the assets folder - is this something that can be done?**

Thank you for your help

Comment: Uninstall your app and install it again

Comment: Is there a way this can be done through the code, so that it happens every time the app starts up?

Comment: No you cant apply changes through code

Comment: Can you write changes to the instance of the database in the data/data folder and then save that to the assets folder?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.
The assets folder is part of the binary APK, which cannot be changed at runtime. You can only change it at compile time.

Comment: Is there a way to force it to re-compile?

Comment: Strange question. Realize that the code is compiled on your PC.